Validation gets lost on tab change
I am using a tab control to group different input fields like text boxes. I am validating the user input of those text boxes via IDataErrorInfo in my view model.
Now, when the user input is not valid and I change the tab pages back and forth the validation indicator disappears from the text box.
I found a possible solution, that the validation must be forced on tab page change. This is working somehow because the validation logic in the VM is executed but the visual indicator on the text box  is still not there.
I already tried updating source and target of the binding and putting the update logic into a Dispatcher.BeginInvoke block with background priority in order to give the UI the chance to render completely. But nothing of that worked. Has anybody an idea which part I am missing out?
My code looks as follows:
the xaml markup
<TabControl SelectionChanged="TabControl_SelectionChanged">

<!-- more tab pages -->

  <TabItem Header="Tab 2">
    <Grid>
      <TextBox Text="{Binding TextProperty, ValidatesOnDataErrors=True}" />
    </Grid>
  </TabItem>
</TabControl>

the code behind
private static IEnumerable<DependencyObject> FindVisualChildren(object obj)
{
  // traverses the visual tree recursively and returns all visual children of obj
}


private void TabControl_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    if (!(e.Source is TabControl tabControl))
    {
        return;
    }
            
    foreach (TabItem tab in tabControl.Items)
    {
        if (!tab.IsSelected)
        {
            continue;
        }
                    
        // Re-validate the controls within the selected tab
        foreach (var child in FindVisualChildren(tab.Content))
        {
            if (child is TextBox textBox)
            {
                var binding = textBox.GetBindingExpression(TextBox.TextProperty);
                binding?.UpdateSource();
            }
        }
    }
}

Solution
Despite the solution mentioned in WPF validation stops working when changing tabs adding a custom style is not applicable in my use case.
But there is a more convenient solution:
Clearing the validation results of the binding forces the wpf glue-logic to re-validate the user input. This brings the validation markers back to the control(s):
Implement the attached property below
public static class RevalidateOnTabChangeBehavior
{
    public static readonly DependencyProperty RevalidateOnTabChangeProperty =
            DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached(
                "RevalidateOnTabChange",
                typeof(bool),
                typeof(RevalidateOnTabChangeBehavior),
                new UIPropertyMetadata(false, OnRevalidateOnTabChangePropertyChanged));

    public static bool GetRevalidateOnTabChange(DependencyObject obj)
    {
        return (bool)obj.GetValue(RevalidateOnTabChangeProperty);
    }

    public static void SetRevalidateOnTabChange(DependencyObject obj, bool revalidateOnTabChange)
    {
        obj.SetValue(RevalidateOnTabChangeProperty, revalidateOnTabChange);
    }

    private static void OnRevalidateOnTabChangePropertyChanged(
            DependencyObject d,
            DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (!(d is TabControl tabControl))
        {
            return;
        }

        if ((bool)e.NewValue)
        {
            tabControl.SelectionChanged += OnTabControlSelectionChanged;
        }
        else
        {
            tabControl.SelectionChanged -= OnTabControlSelectionChanged;
        }
    }
        
    private static void OnTabControlSelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (!(e.Source is TabControl tabControl))
        {
            return;
        }
            
        foreach (TabItem tab in tabControl.Items)
        {
            if (!tab.IsSelected)
            {
                continue;
            }
                  
            // Re-validate the controls within the selected tab
            foreach (var child in FindVisualChildren(tab.Content))
            {
                if (!(child is TextBox textBox))
                {
                    continue;
                }
                    
                var binding = textBox.GetBindingExpression(TextBox.TextProperty);
                if (binding == null)
                {
                    continue;
                }
                        
                Validation.ClearInvalid(binding);
                binding.UpdateSource();
            }
        }
    }
        
    private static IEnumerable<DependencyObject> FindVisualChildren(object parent)
    {
        if (!(parent is DependencyObject dependencyObject))
        {
            yield break;
        }
            
        for (var i = 0; i < VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(dependencyObject); i++)
        {
            var child = VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(dependencyObject, i);

            yield return child;

            foreach (var childOfChild in FindVisualChildren(child))
            {
                yield return childOfChild;
            }
        }
    }
}

And add this snippet into the xaml of the Tab control:
<TabControl  
  behaviors:RevalidateOnTabChangeBehavior.RevalidateOnTabChange="True"
    SelectionChanged="TabControl_SelectionChanged">

...


TabControl uses virtualization for its pages, switching page will wipe out all uncommited into ViewModel changes. Either disable virtualization or use a validation method, which stores invalid state in ViewModel.

I got it. You have to clear validation results before triggering validation in order for the UI to show the validation indicator: Validation.ClearInvalid(binding);

Since .NET 4.5 the recommended way for data validation is to implement INotifyDataErrorInfo (instead of the old IDataErrorInfo).

@BionicCode Yep, but INotifyDataErrorInfo does not change the behavior. Even when the event is invoked again, the indicator in the UI stays invisible.

@Sinatr the problem is that there is no easy way to turn virtualization off for the TabControl…

I know that your observed behavior is not related to IDataErrorInfo. This was just a general recommendation. You can find the explanation if you follow the above link WPF validation stops working when changing tabs. It's not necessary to turn virtualization off to solve this. Unless you know you really don't need it. The link provides a simple solution.

@BionicCode thanks for the explanation. The issue is that we use a third party UI lib which contains styling for controls and thus we cannon implement a custom style for the validation message (or would have to reimplement the one from the lib which is not a viable solution to us). I added my solution, which I mentioned in the comment above, to the original question.
